# Changing views with a ListBoxItem rather than a Button?

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have a single page with a sidebar (Menu Items), top bar and a big main area.  I can get my code to work if I make my sidebar items buttons.  In my design I have a Listbox of items that's just text ***I don't want to use buttons***.

**Goal:**  Is to select a menu item in the left side bar and change the view in the main area.

I'm very new to MVVM and there is lots of good content on this site and youtube but I haven't found an example that uses text, it's always with buttons which doesn't help me.

I wish I could do something like this.

```
<ListBoxItem x:Name="Customer" 
   Command={Binding UpdateViewCommand} 
   CommandParameter = "Customer"
</ListBoxItem>
```

I'll explain what I have.

**LeftSideBar.xaml**

```
<Grid>
   <ListBox IsSelected="True" SelectionMode="Single">
      <ListBoxItem x:Name="Customer">
         <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock>Customers</TextBlock>
         </StackPanel>
      </ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem x:Name="Security">
         <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock>Security</TextBlock>
         </StackPanel>
      </ListBoxItem>
   </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

**LeftSideBar.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class LeftSideBar : UserControl
{
   public LeftSideBar()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window.Resources>    
   <DataTemplate x:Name="homeViewTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:HomeViewModel}">
      <view:HomeView DataContext="{Binding}"/>    
   </DataTemplate>    
   <DataTemplate x:Name="customerViewTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:CustomerViewModel}">
      <view:CustomerView DataContext="{Binding}"/>    
   </DataTemplate>    
   <DataTemplate x:Name="securityViewTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:SecurityViewModel}">
      <view:SecurityView DataContext="{Binding}"/>    
   </DataTemplate> 
 </Window.Resources>  

<Grid>        
   <controls:TopBar></controls:TopBar> 
   <controls:LeftSideBar></controls:LeftSideBar>        
   <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}"/> 
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   public MainWindow()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      DataContext = new MainViewModel();
   }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
internal class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
   private BaseViewModel _selectedViewModel = new HomeViewModel();
   public BaseViewModel SelectedViewModel
   {
      get { return _selectedViewModel; }
      set { _selectedViewModel = value; }
   }
}
```

**UpdateViewCommand.cs**

```
public class UpdateViewCommand : ICommand
{
   private MainViewModel ViewModel;
   public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
   public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
      {throw new NotImplementedException();}

   public void Execute(object parameter)
      {throw new NotImplementedException();}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty example on how you could do that, you will have to adjust it to your needs.

Just wrap your text inside a type with a command... or whatever else you see fit.

[image]

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new[]
            {
                new Item {Text = "abcd", Command = new RelayCommand(s => MessageBox.Show("abcd!"))},
                new Item {Text = "efgh", Command = new RelayCommand(s => MessageBox.Show("efgh!"))},
                new Item {Text = "ijkl", Command = new RelayCommand(s => MessageBox.Show("ijkl!"))}
            };
        }

        private void Selector_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e?.AddedItems?[0] is Item item)
            {
                item.Command.Execute(null);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public ICommand Command { get; set; }
    }

    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;
        private readonly Action<object> _execute;

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, _ => true)
        {
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute)
        {
            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object? parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object? parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler? CanExecuteChanged;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox SelectionChanged="Selector_OnSelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="local:Item">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```